# context processor equivalent in pure jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm using "pure jinja" in python:

```
jinja2.Environment()
```

I need a "filter" that works on 2 paramters

```
{{ foo(param1, param2) }}
```

When foo does a non trivial manipulation on the params
Similar to the behaviour of flask's context paramter
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/templating/#context-processors

Is there something similar in jinja?